# Datatable - Using linq I want to update a row with the count

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a C# datatable with:

```
Id        ParentId    Name
========  =========== =====
1                     A
2          1          b
3          1          c
4          2          d
6          5          e
```

I want to add a column or just the result that will identify any `ParentId`s that do not have an `Id`. Basically in the above table, I want to find `Id=6` since `ParentId` 5 is invalid.

I want to identify anywhere a `parentId` is not listed as an `Id`

I thought this could be accomplish with Linq.

Comment: A column in the database?  In a data structure that houses these database values?  It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish and you haven't shown us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Sorry, That was unclear. I updated the question.  I basically want to know the records that have invalid ParentIds

Comment: How are we supposed to understand that ParentId is invalid, given the data you've shown? What determines if a ParentId is valid or not? I would have expected the query to return `Id 1`, since it does not have a ParentId.

Comment: Yes. I am looking for it to return 1 and 6.  I know how to query this in a DB but I am not sure how to do this without iterating through the datatabe

Answer (score 1):

This will return all rows where the `ParentId` does not appear in any row as `Id`

```
rows.Where(r1 => !rows.Any(r2 => r1["ParentId"] == r2["Id"]))
```

Comment: That seems like the correct, but it didnt work. I did the following
var  rows = dtOrgPlus.Select();
var mismatchrows = rows.Where(r1 => !rows.Any(r2 => r1["Parent"] == r2["Id"]));